# Why I Can see the result of the operation that provide Deferred Execution (LINQ)?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-xml

As I know that there are some operations in LINQ that provide deferred execution means that the operation will not be executed until I try to pull something from `IEnumerable`.

[image: Code Source]

If that's the case why when I start debugging my app I can see the result of the Where operation that means the where operation was executed ?

[image: Debugging]

Comment: You clicked "Results View", now read the remark by that command.

Comment: Avoid putting code as image.

Comment: "Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable". Just **read** intelisense-tooltip before expanding.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66116570/491907

Comment: Thank you I didn't notice the remark

Comment: The debugger is there to help you. But sometimes is also there to distract you. And instead of debugging your application, you end up debugging the debugger. In those cases, Ctrl+F5 is your friend (Start Without Debugging).